# Find generating function expressing number of rectangles

Tags: generating-functions

I have a 3 x n rectangle. I need to find a generating function expressing the number of little 1 x 3 rectangles inside this bigger one. How can I do this? I have no idea how to even begin.

Comment: Can you find a recurrence relation?

Comment: It would be great if I'd found one, but I can't come up with any here.

Comment: Step 1; figure out the number of little rectangles for a few small values of $n$. Step 2; look up the resulting sequence of numbers in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $a_{n+3} = a_n+a_{n+2}$.

**Expanded:** $a_n$ obviously, is the number of tilings of a $3\times n$ rectangle. Now, consider a $3\times (n+3)$ rectangle. In any tiling, the bottom left corner is either tiled by a vertical tile, or a horizontal tile. In the first case, the rest of the is $3 \times (n+2)$ and can be tiled $a_{n+2}$ ways. Otherwise, the cell just above the bottom left has to be tiled by a horizontal tile, and same for the one above it. In which case the rest is a $3 \times n$ rectangle, which can be tiled $a_n$ ways. These cases are obviously mutually exclusive.

The answer seems to be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x-x^3}$$.

Comment: How? I don't know how to combine recurrence solution with this problem, could you describe this a bit please? I'll owe you one :P

Comment: Added the derivation of the recurrence relation, and the answer (assuming I did the calculations correctly). If you are not clear on the explanation, or how to proceed from there, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much, most of the things are clear to me now. So I get the recurrence equation (few first values and the recurrence formula), and I just have to solve this, and that's it?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing you know how to solve such recurrences via generating functions.

Answer (score -2):

This is in particular equation (9) in *Tilings of Rectangular Regions by Rectangular Tiles: Counts Derived from Transfer Matrices*, [ArXiv:1406.7788](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7788)  by Richard J. Mathar.